# Change luggage with Ryanair

Tags: luggage, budget, ryanair

I just want to ask if I am going to fly with RyanAir but a friend ordered bag luggage *1 priority* and *2 cabin bags*, but I will have only 1 bag but bigger than *55 x 40 x 20 cm*.

How much it will change it to bigger version if is possible?

I found out that is something like 40 € after the booking has been made, but I just need to be sure.

Comment: Where did you find that number? Presumably from Ryanair? If so, then there's your answer

Comment: No i find it online. But maybe somebody here know.

Comment: Have you checked the Ryanair site for this information?

Comment: I found this https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/fees but its my first time i am traveling with airplane so i just want to be sure how it works. And yes more minuses helps to solve situation thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can add a checked-in bag](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/baggage/20-kg-check-in-bag) by modifying your booking online up to 2 hours before check-in, or at the baggage drop counter at the airport. The cost is 25 GBP/EUR if done upon booking the flight and 40 GBP/EUR if done after booking the flight. In general, it is cheaper to do this online and not at the baggage drop counter. Quoting from the linked website:

> ### Steps to add
>
> Bags can be purchased either when making the initial booking or can be added to a reservation via the My Booking facility up to 2 hours before the scheduled flight departure time.
>
> ### Cost
>
> The 20kg check-in bag costs €/£25 if purchased while booking the flight, and costs €/£40 after the booking is made.
>
> Checked bags are non-refundable, are charged per person, per one way flight, and cannot be swapped between passengers or changed to other bag options. *Higher bag fees apply when checked bags are purchased via a Ryanair call centre, at airport ticket desks, during peak periods and on selected routes.

Comment: We just paid 20euro for extending our (one) bagguage because it was too big.

Comment: @Durinko before or after booking? At the airport?

Comment: At the airport.